# parenthesis matching using doubly linked list in c++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, parentheses

I am trying to make a parenthesis matching program using doubly linked list in c++
I confirmed that my Dlink class does work when I try the Dlink class alone. however when I make a Dlink object inside my parenthesis mactching class the character doesn't seem to go in the doubly linked list. I can't find where I messed up the code.

here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class DNode {
private:
    char data;
    DNode *next;
    DNode *prev;
    friend class Dlink;
};


class Dlink {
private:
public:
    Dlink();
    ~Dlink();
    bool empty() const;
    void addfront(char);
    void removefront();
    void addback(char);
    void removeback();
    void add(DNode*, const char);
    void remove(DNode *);
    const char& front() const;
    const char& back() const;
    int size();
    void print();
    int n;
private:
    DNode * head;
    DNode *tail;
};


Dlink::Dlink() {
    head = new DNode;
    tail = new DNode;
    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
    n = 0;
}


Dlink::~Dlink() {
    while (!empty()) removefront();
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}


void Dlink::add(DNode *v, const char e) {
    DNode *u = new DNode;
    u->data = e;
    u->next = v;
    u->prev = v->prev;
    v->prev->next = u;
    v->prev = u;
    n++;
}

void Dlink::addfront(const char e) {
    add(head->next, e);
}

void Dlink::addback(const char e) {
    add(tail, e);
}

void Dlink::remove(DNode *v) {
    DNode *u = v->prev;
    DNode *w = v->next;
    u->next = w;
    w->prev = u;
    delete v;
    n--;
}

void Dlink::removefront() {
    remove(head->next);
}

void Dlink::removeback() {
    remove(tail->prev);
}

bool Dlink::empty() const {
    return (head->next == tail);
}

const char& Dlink::front() const {
    return head->next->data;
}

const char& Dlink::back() const {
    return tail->prev->data;
}

int Dlink::size() {
    return n;
}

void Dlink::print() {
    cout << front() << endl;
}

class parenthesis {
private:
    Dlink d;
public:
    parenthesis(char[], int);
    ~parenthesis();
    char str[20];
    int i;
    int flag;
    int j = 0;
    bool domatch();
    bool isopen(char);
    bool isclose(char);
    int type(char);
    char a;
};

parenthesis::parenthesis(char str[], int size) {
    str = str;
    i = size;
}

parenthesis::~parenthesis() {}

bool parenthesis::isopen(char a) {
    a = a;
    if (a == '(' || a == '{' || a == '[') return true;
    else return false;
}

bool parenthesis::isclose(char a) {
    a = a;
    if (a == ')' ||a == '}' || a == ']') return true;
    else return false;
}

int parenthesis::type(char a) {
    a = a;
    if (a == ')' || a == '(') return 1;
    else if (a == '}' || a == '{') return 2;
    else if (a == ']' || a == '[') return 3;
}

bool parenthesis::domatch() {
    if (isclose(str[j])) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (isopen(str[j])) {
        d.addfront(str[j]);
        flag = 1;
        j++;
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        for (j; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (isopen(str[j])) {
                d.addfront(str[j]);
            }                     
            else if (isclose(str[j])) {                                     
                if (type(d.front()) == type(str[j])) d.removefront();   
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!d.empty()) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    cout << "enter string" << endl;
    cin >> str;
    parenthesis p1 = parenthesis(str, strlen(str));
    return p1.domatch();
}
```

Comment: *I am trying to make a parenthesis matching program using doubly linked list* -- Unusual.  You usually use a stack or similar data structure to solve this problem, not a linked list.  Also solutions using a stack use far less code than what you've written.

Comment: I agree that using Stack would be much easier but the assignment says I need to use doubly linked list.

Comment: If you need a doubly linked list you can just use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). No need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DLink class experiences [rule of 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) breach. It got resposibility for chain of nodes.

```
 parenthesis p1 = parenthesis(str, strlen(str));
```

This initialization wouldn't work, because DLink doesn't have proper copy constructor.. pointers will be left dangling after temporal instance of `parenthesis` and `DLink` inside it are destroyed.

Easy fix is to use smart pointer in DLink, that would follow Rule of All or Nothing, while smart pointer would destroy list only when it isn't used anymore. Or create copy or move constructor, if assigment does not allow use of library classes.

Just for assigment you can avoid usage of temporal object at all, but you should be aware of this pitfall.

Comment: what if I do  parenthesis *p1 = new parenthesis(str, strlen(str));   ?  does it still breach rule of 3? I'm sorry I don't really no about rule of 3 ....

Comment: @윤준한 I gave link. Yes, that's one way, even while it does not remove problem underlying class. another way is `parenthesis p{str, strlen(str)};`

Comment: I just deleted the parenthesis class and made a paranthesis function and now it works. But I still don't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: @윤준한 because you didn't wrote `DLink` in way it could be copied.